# Alternative Fuel types for motor vehicles

Tags: science-based, fuels

I have this world where aircraft don't exist and water travel is nigh zero, so all travel and transport over any distance too long to reasonably walk is done by car/van/bus/truck etc.

Nearly every vehicle in this world can attain speeds that on earth would only be allowed on racetracks and traffic basically looks like an 80's race/police/road action movie. (rule of cool is in effect in regards to how this is possible without extremely high fatality numbers)

But seeing how driving is basically a cultural thing in this world i wanted to have a lot of variety in types of cars regarding how they work and thus also in what fuels their engines.

This is the part where i want something that is at least plausible (no matter if in real life it would be impractical)

I imagine fuel stations in this world to have way more varieties of fuel available.
So apart from your standard gasoline, diesel, gas and electricity, what are some other substances (gas or liquid) that could theoretically be used to power a car? (Can be uncommon but no extremely rare substances that nearly no one knows even exists)

note: if possible i would want to have at least one liquid fuel that is very eco-friendly among all the types.

Comment: Please change the question to not ask a (potentially endless) list.

Comment: @L.Dutch how would you suggest i word it then?

Comment: for example you might give some constraints (not "anything goes" like you are asking now) or focus on a specific type and ask if it is plausible.

Comment: Would restricting it to only gasses and liquids be enough constraints?

Comment: try posting the question in the sandbox, you will get help by other users to refine it

Comment: I would also appreciate some restrictions. Look at [the wiki page for fuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel); anything that burns can theoretically be used. @BlueDevil try to find some theme or restriction for every answer. Like your liquid eco-friendly substance; if you focus on just that then we can answer with organic oils and such.

Comment: Instead of asking for a list, you should ask for a single fuel that best meets your criteria, as asking for exhaustive lists is considered off topic.  If need be, you can ask multiple questions like best fuel not commonly used today for: cheapness, another for Eco-friendliness, another for  easiness to make yourself... When you ask more targeted questions like this, not only is it more on topic, but you will get much better suggestions since each fuel source will have an actual reason to exist in your world.

Comment: This is *Rule of Cool* --- mundanity, while plausible, is not sufficient!

Answer (score 2):

### Hydrogen

Hydrogen is a great fuel which generates energy by reacting with oxygen. The only waste product is pure water, so it's very environmentally friendly (as long as you don't consider the production chain for the hydrogen, which [*can* be environmentally friendly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_hydrogen) but [doesn't *has* to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_reforming)).

And it's not science fiction. [Mass-produced hydrogen vehicles exist for decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_vehicle).

There are three options for turning hydrogen into velocity:

- [Hydrogen fuel cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell), which turn hydrogen and oxygen into electricity and use it to drive an electric engine.
- [Hydrogen internal combustion engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_internal_combustion_engine_vehicle), which work very similar to regular internal combustion engines. Although keep in mind that if you use regular air as an oxidizer and not pure oxygen, then it also produces nitrogen-oxides, which aren't environmentally friendly.
- [Liquid fuel rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_rocket_propellant#Hydrogen) using liquefied hydrogen and liquefied oxygen. In case you want [some **serious** speed rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_car).

Answer (score 1):

## Coal and/or logs

Steam powered cars are a thing and some can reach speeds over 160 mph (~250 km/h). There are even racing contests in some places of the world.

## Uranium

1 kg of uraniun is worth tons of coal in power. I believe companies like BMW have had concept uranium powered cars in the past.

Answer (score 1):

### Alcohol

High-proof ethanol [makes a very efficient liquid fuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol_fuel) and thanks to how little technology is required to mass-produce it, it is a very plausible option for a post-apocalyptic world.

Regarding its environmental impact: it's made 100% from plants, so it's carbon-neutral. However, burning alcohol creates carbon monoxide and aldehydes, which are pretty unhealthy.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a large variety of fuels used for combustion engines, sticking only to internal combustion engines you could have:

- **[Wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_gas)** Most likely in a chip or pellet type for ease of distribution, but it could be sawn up logs.  During past wars when petroleum was limited many farm vehicles were converted to run on wood gas.
- **[Compressed Natural Gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_natural_gas#Motor_vehicles) (AKA Methane)** This is currently utilized technology with about 15 million cars world wide and a fully functional distribution system down to local filling stations.
- **[Hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_vehicle)**  Although there are many problems with storage, distribution, and safety, Hydrogen has been used as a motor vehicle combustion fuel on quite a number of test vehicles and a small number of production cars.
- **[Alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_fuel)** Ethanol is now commonly used as a fuel additive in most gasoline for its effects on emission controls.  Combustion engines can run on blended gas all the way up to 100% alcohol.
- **[Ammonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia#Other)**  Large amounts of ammonia are produced for use as a feedstock for fertilizers and has been experimented with as a liquid fuel.  Generally not used due to its hazardous nature and many potential problems with handling.
- **[Plant or Animal Fats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable_oil_fuel)** Vegetable oil or animal greases are commonly used to produce bio-diesel and engines can be made which will run on the oils directly.  For possibly the least eco-friendly option I would propose using Whale-Oil.

Answer (score 1):

##### Rubbish & Expired Salty Snax

Since this is Rule of Cool territory, one might think that technically speaking, anything can be a potential answer to the question. And, one would think wrong! Wood? Used cooking oil? That's so *real world!*

***Whatever you throw in it, Mr Fusion can power it!***

Your fuel station will be a veritable recycling depot where people bring in a wide variety of materials to be used as fuel. For those who can afford the device, the left-over bin at the edge of the parking lot makes it all worthwhile! This is where all the cool and bizarre stuff can be found. Half drunk bottles of Red Bull, stale cat litter clumps, liquified schwartz, pee, missing Watergate tapes, chicken bones, Jimmy Hoffa. Mr Fusion is not picky!

[image: https://www.universetoday.com/98968/nasas-version-of-mr-fusion/]

Answer (score 1):

## Steam (plus anything combustible)

Steam powered vehicles are, of course, very real. They tend towards slow because of the weight of boilers, but big ones are basically locomotives (which are, of course, quite fast). Anything that can burn can be used as fuel, including wood, coal, oil, and gas. The ultimate flex fuel concept.

Answer (score 0):

**Pure alkali or alkaline metal plus water.**
Their reaction produces hydrogen which could be detonated immediately in the reaction chamber or in a next step, or could be sent to a fuel cell. The alkali must be kept in a water tight container to avoid oxidation, but on the other hand it does not need pressurised containers and the energy density will be higher.

**Compressed air.**
Here on earth compressed air engines for car failed because nobody found a way to control the freezing effect of air expansion and mechanic parts used to become brittle and crack. But in another world things might be slightly different.

**Synthetic fuel.**
Gasoline and diesel can also be produced by reforming methane, so they could be available in many different worlds even if dead organic matter is scarce.

**Electric induction.**
If they move only alongside few established racetracks they could also have electric cables buried beneath providing energy by induction. Fuel stations would not be needed, but maintenance and service station would still be there. However this will be possible in a place with a lot of copper and energy available.